Correlation functions zero for repeated creation or annihilation operators
In the derivation of the damped harmonic oscillator, at some point, see for instance here one has to compute certain correlation functions for the bath of harmonic oscillators in thermal equilibrium. Why correlation functions like $\langle \Gamma^\dagger(t)\Gamma^\dagger(t')\rangle$ are zero, with $\Gamma^\dagger(t) = \sum_j k_j b_j^\dagger e^{iw_j t}$?
Okey, the zero has to come from computing the trace
$$
{\rm Tr}(R_0 b_j^\dagger b_k^\dagger)=0,
$$
but I don't see easily why this is the case. Here $R_0$ isthe density matrix of the bath composed of $n$-harmonic oscillators in thermal equilibrium. Carmichael mentions that this is super-obvious if one write this in the multimode Fock states,but I can't see why.

Does this answer your question? Gibbs state and creation and annihilation operators See also my comments for literature.


Okey, the zero has to come from computing the trace
$$
{\rm Tr}(R_0 b_j^\dagger b_k^\dagger)=0,
$$
but I don't see easily why this is the case.


Here $R_0$ is the density matrix of the bath composed of $n$-harmonic oscillators in thermal equilibrium.

For concreteness, I will assume a form like:
$$
R_0 = e^{-\beta \hat H}\;,
$$
where
$$
\hat H = \sum_{i}\omega_i \hat b_i^\dagger \hat b_i\;,
$$
where $i$ indexes the mode. Note that such a Hamiltonian commutes with the number operator $\hat N = \sum_{i}b^\dagger_i b_i$. Note further that the result will hold regardless of the specific form of the Hamiltonian as long as the Hamiltonian commutes with the number operator.

Carmichael mentions that this is super-obvious if one write this in the multimode Fock states,but I can't see why.

Fock states with different "numbers of particles" are orthogonal. Or, in terms of "modes," states with different total number of mode excitations are orthogonal. (This is because eigenstates of an operator that have different eigenvalues are orthogonal, which is a basic results of linear algebra.)
In the occupation number basis we can write eigenstates of the Hamiltonian as:
$$
|n_1; n_2, n_3,\ldots\rangle\;,
$$
where $n_i$ tells us the number of particles in mode $i$. Note that we are allowed to take the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian as eigenstates of the number operator, since the two operators commute.
We have:
$$
{\rm Tr}(R_0 b_j^\dagger b_k^\dagger)=\sum_{n_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty\ldots
\langle n_1, n_2,\ldots|e^{-\beta H}b_j^\dagger b_k^\dagger|n_1,n_2,\ldots\rangle
$$
$$
\sum_{n_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty\ldots
e^{-\beta E(n_1,n_2,\ldots)}\langle n_1, n_2,\ldots|b_j^\dagger b_k^\dagger|n_1,n_2,\ldots\rangle\;.
$$
But
$$
\langle n_1, n_2,\ldots,n_k,\ldots, n_j,\ldots|b_j^\dagger b_k^\dagger|n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k,\ldots, n_j,\ldots\ldots\rangle
$$
$$
=\sqrt{n_k+1}\sqrt{n_j+1}\langle n_1, n_2,\ldots,n_k,\ldots, n_j,\ldots|n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k+1,\ldots, n_j+1,\ldots\ldots\rangle
$$
$$
=0\;,
$$
since states with different numbers of excited modes are orthogonal.
